# Android page curl by harism, show a View together pagecurl into a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, curl

I have a problem to show a View together with/using pagecurl in a RelativeLayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<com.harism.customview.curlview.CurlView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/curl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" >
</com.harism.customview.curlview.CurlView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/img"
    android:visibility="invisible" >
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have added a callback that makes the bottom RelativeLayout visible (@+id/img") when the page is changed. The RelativeLayout is not shown immediately, but if i put the background the application and then restore it the Relative layout becomes visible.
I other words i can't becomes visible the image programmatically.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question...the solution was simple...
I've used in the layout
android:visibility="gone" >

instead of

android:visibility="invisible" >

and when i change page the image is showed

bye